# Get Data for ArcPad extension and python

Tags: python, arcpad

Is it possible to call the 'Get Data for ArcPad' extension using python?  If so would someone be willing to share their code?

Comment: What ArcGIS version and ArcPad version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. **ArcPad comes with a toolbox and geoprocessing tools**. There are two tools that might be of interest, the ArcPad Checkout and the ArcPad check in. **If you export them to py** you will learn their arcpy parameters and variables.

```
    arcpy.ArcPadCheckout_ArcPad("", "", "", "", "", "", "", The_full_path_and_name_of_the_AXF)
```

[image]